# R - Loop to get ARMA coeftest output in list

Tags: r, loops

R-newbie question.

I have some troubles understanding how to compute the coeftest function on ALL looped ARMA models and display the related output in the list.

How would you most simply adjust the following code?

```
library(lmtest)

bchain_2012_logreturns=diff(log(prices_2012))
bchain_2013_logreturns=diff(log(prices_2013))

bchain_logreturns_Arima_coef=list()
k=1
for(i in 2012:2013){
for(p in 0:1){
for(q in 0:1){         
bchain_logreturns_Arima=Arima(get(paste("bchain_",i,"_logreturns",sep="")),order=c(p,0,q))
bchain_logreturns_Arima_coef[[k]]=round(transpose(coeftest(bchain_logreturns_Arima)),digit=3)
}
}
k=k+1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand how accumulator k works. Now it' fine.

```
library(lmtest)

bchain_2012_logreturns=diff(log(prices_2012))
bchain_2013_logreturns=diff(log(prices_2013))

bchain_logreturns_Arima_coef=list()
k=1
for(i in 2012:2013){
for(p in 0:1){
for(q in 0:1){         
bchain_logreturns_Arima=Arima(get(paste("bchain_",i,"_logreturns",sep="")),order=c(p,0,q))
bchain_logreturns_Arima_coef[[k]]=round(transpose(coeftest(bchain_logreturns_Arima)),digit=3)
k=k+1
}
}
}
```